# android spinner size automatically changed?

Tags: android, exception, user-interface

before adapter set.
[image]

after adapter set.
  [image]

My Xml Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin_filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin_sort"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

  </LinearLayout>
  <View
    style="@style/Divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />
 ..........

 </LinearLayout>
```

I want to display the spinners same width. every spinner have to 50 percentage of parent width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the layout_width as 0dp for both spinners.

Answer (score 2):

Change spinners'

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="0px"
```

so that the content width doesn't affect the spinner width and it's only the layout weight that distributes width to your spinners.